# Power Spectral Density Reconstruction

Tags: audio, power-spectral-density, spectrogram, reconstruction

I am from an ML background and I am working on MP3 audio reconstruction and I have managed some amount of spectrogram reconstruction but I have noticed that the higher frequency end of the generated Power Spectral Density plot(Wave2) isn't matching with the original audio's plot (Wave1).

[image]

There is a similar distribution in the magnitude spectrum which is obvious since the two are linked. I wanted to know if there is any way I could regenerate the higher frequency power (or magnitude) because I cannot map the input PSD data to output PSD data as there is no way to convert the PSD data back to an audio clip even if I am successful in mapping them. The real and imaginary part re-constructions for the spectrogram reconstruction are visually pretty accurate but I am still unsure about how to approach this issue. Any guidance would be great!

Comment: well, that's lossy compression to you: it doesn't contain all the original information. What's surprising about that?

Comment: And why would you reconstruct audio from the spectrogram instead of directly from the MP3? A spectrogram isn't uniquely mappable to audio (i.e. many very different pieces of audio have the same magnitude spectrum), whereas the MP3 data as is has a single optimum interpretation -> kick the spectrogram out of your signal processing chain, it loses info.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was working with Spectrograms because I had to perform a spectrogram reconstruction as well (I initially thought just re-creating the higher frequencies would work but I was wrong). I know they are lossy but they were the best option I had. I managed to get the reconstructed spectrogram to match the original audio but the magnitude spectrum is still off. I was hoping that there could be a specific way of representing the audio data through which I could reconstruct the magnitude information too, so that the spectrogram changes would actually be a bit more humanly audible.

Comment: nope, you really want to go MP3->audio directly, I promise.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Could you explain a bit more specifically on what exactly "MP3->audio directly" means?

Comment: It means that you should train your neural network to reconstruct the audio from the MP3 data input, not just the spectrogram

Comment: @MarcusMüller There isn't much difference in the amplitudes of the files because there is only a change in bit-rates of the files. The amplitude-time graphs show no visible differences [Graph sample](https://i.imgur.com/nogkeWm.png) . So I dont think passing this time series through a neural network will yield the results I require

Comment: I might then simply be misunderstanding what you want – in that case, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations

1. Your pictures looks odd. "Wave 1" doesn't look like an original audio file but something that has already been encoded/decoded and aggressively lowpass filtered in the process. Your reconstructed audio (Wave 2) actually as MORE high frequency energy, which I suspect is simply just quantization noise from the other bands. The expected spectrum of music is roughly pink (3dB/octave) up to about 10 kHz and then a steeper decline (maybe 10dB octave) to 20 kHz and above. There shouldn't be a step function in the spectrum.
2. The standard method of recovering for lost high frequency spectrum is Spectral Replication. That's been already implemented in some of the more modern codec standards (e.g. AAC) although not in MP3. See for example http://www.stockis.se/AES112th_SBR.pdf
3. If you want to do any commercial work in this area, I highly recommend studying the patent situation carefully.  A massive amount of work has already been done in this field and since the license revenue is quite substantial, the work has been well protected by patents and there is incentive to enforce them.

Comment: Yes the Wave 1 is also an MP3 file so it has been passed through an encoder beforehand. Thanks for the link to the paper but I have managed to recover most of the frequency spectrum through a spectrogram but turns out that only spectrogram reconstruction isn't enough to make it sound like the original sample. Magnitude and power spectrums are the only spectrums not matching (phase matches satisfactorily) and since both are correlated, I figured they are the key to the audio actually sounding similar to the original. Any idea how I can work on the magnitude or power spectrum specifically?